# Mounting a image dynamically from drawable on click of imageview

Tags: android

### I am trying to mount a image dynamically from drawable on click of imageview

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**What i am trying to do** ::

- On click of imageview a pop-up to upload image from drawables
- where i can select a single image from the list of images in
  drawables

---

**How can this be achieved** ?

Comment: Have you tried the Gallery ?

Comment: You can create a custom `dialog` for this with a custom `listView` since the number of images in the drawable folder is limited an show the dialog when the user clicks on the imageView

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: @user2247689 ..... I am trying to fetch images from drawables .... I am using emulator(not a mobile device)

Comment: You can create an array to put all the images and show it in listview as a dialog.

Comment: @insomniac ....... Can u show an example as your answer using my code i posted ?

Comment: @Yugesh ..... Can you please edit your i/p as the answer

Comment: @NewBie you want fetch all images from SD card or the images from resource folder(Images in app folder).

Comment: yes, wait for sometime i'll give the link to the code,what you posted is not what you've tried so far .this code is automatically generated,and don't expect me to give whole code

Comment: @Yugesh .....  the images from resource folder(Images in app folder).

Comment: @NewBie `int[] image_array = {R.drawable.img,R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3}` using this image array to show it in customized list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom dialog box with a custom listview like this [image]The code for the custom dialog box can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659766/Android-Custom-DialogBox)
and you can add the custom list view from the code given [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)